# zabbix 4.4 frontend 503 error for assests

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, zabbix

I am trying to setup a zabbix server, to which I will eventually connect remote agent hosts. Zabbix's claim to be up and running in 5 minutes seems to be a little misleading, but that is for another day

I installed zabbix 4.4 using the rpm packages on a CentOS 7 server. After configuring the MySql database, the zabbix-server.conf, etc. I open a browser and receive some weird issues.

The first issue, opening http://[host ip address]/zabbix, returns `The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`

If I then try http://[host ip address]/zabbix/index.php, I see the screen but there is no styling.

[image]

Using Chrome browser I opened the developer tools and see several 503 errors (service unavailable) in the console.

[image]

Researching this, I've found where I may have to change the owner and set permissions so I

```
chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/zabbix
chmod -R =x /usr/share/zabbix
```

That has not helped.

There are no errors in either /var/log/httpd/access_log or error_log. I've enabled php to log errors, `error_log = /var/log/php/php_errors.log` and created the parent directory /var/log/php, but no file has been generated

I'm not sure what else to do.

Setup and Configuration:

- OS: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 Apache: Server version:
- Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
- PHP: 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 08:36:40)
- /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf:

```
#
# Zabbix monitoring system php web frontend
#

Alias /zabbix /usr/share/zabbix

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value max_execution_time 300
        php_value memory_limit 128M
        php_value post_max_size 16M
        php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
        php_value max_input_time 300
        php_value max_input_vars 10000
        php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
        php_value date.timezone America/New_York
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/conf">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/app">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/include">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/local">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Everything I have read points to a misconfiguration of Apache, but I think I've been through everything I can think of.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post your apache configuration file.  Does Zabbix have an error log? Post any apache error log and Zabbix error log that is available, please. The documented 503 errors are files that are not available to load and their names are listed.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you for the comments. Unfortunately, I have moved away from zabbix